# Use of @lends in controls

Tags: jsdoc, sapui5

I've seen the *lends* annotation used in the OpenUI5 code in places (such as https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Slider.js#L28) but I'm not quite clear on it's purpose.

For example, in sap.m.Slider there is:

```
var Slider = Control.extend("sap.m.Slider", /** @lends sap.m.Slider.prototype */ { metadata: {
```

Any ideas?

**Update**:

Turns out the answer was to look through the [JSDoc doc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-lends.html). See 1st comment below...

Comment: Heres the documentation for the jsdoc @lends annotation: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-lends.html
That might make things clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-lends.html

```
The @lends tag allows you to document all the members of an 
object literal as if they were members of a symbol with the given name. 

You might want to do this if you are passing an object literal 
into a function that creates a named class from its members.
```